# ¿Cómo corregir un caracter en un data frame?

Tags: r

Como corregir un caracter en un `data frame` por ejemplo quiero cambiar la palabra `roma` por `Roma`

```
25       Roma                   56
26       Roma                45.32
27       Roma                44.34
28       roma                85.23
29       roma                44.23
30       Roma                44.29
```

Datos para reproducir:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 25:30, V2 = c("Roma", "Roma", "Roma", "roma", 
"roma", "Roma"), V3 = c(56, 45.32, 44.34, 85.23, 44.23, 44.29
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: evaluacion1[evaluacion1== "roma"]<-"Roma"
evaluacion1[evaluacion1== "bariloche"]<-"Bariloche"
evaluacion1
evaluacion1[evaluacion1== "Variloche"]<-"Bariloche"
evaluacion1
str(evaluacion1)
evaluacion1$ciudad

Comment: Sabes que lo hice como me indicaste, y me sigue saliendo que la columna ciudad tiene 6 niveles, en vez de 3, que puede estar mal?

Answer (score 2):

La forma más simple es modificando la palabra completa:

```
df[df == 'roma'] <- 'Roma'
```

`df == 'roma'` te retorna una matriz de valores lógicos de aquellos valores que sean igual a `roma`, únicamente a estos le asignas el nuevo valor `'Roma'`. El problema que tiene esta solución, es que solo considera palabras completas, es decir con `roma citta aperta` no va a considerara la palabra `roma` dentro de la oración. Si este fuera el caso y siguiendo con la lógica de usar R base, podrías usar `gsub()` para reemplazar parcialmente en cada columna:

```
# Vamos a modificar solo las columnas que sean del tipo caracter
col.a.modificar <- sapply(df, is.character)
df[, col.a.modificar] <- apply(df[, col.a.modificar, drop=FALSE], 2, FUN = function(x){gsub('roma', 'Roma', x)})
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, voy a probar con la primera opcion, ya que son palabras solas, es decir, no oraciones

Answer (score 1):

Algunas alternativas usando las funciones del `tidyverse`:

1. Para el caso más general en el que quieres normalizar todas las cadenas de caracteres en la variable V2, de modo que siempre tengan la primera letra en mayúsculas se puede usar `str_to_title` que hace exactamente eso:

   ```
   library(tidyverse)  
   df %>%   
     mutate(V2 = str_to_title(V2))
   ```
2. Si te interesa cambiar solamente `roma` por `Roma` se puede usar `str_replace`, para reemplazar cadenas de caracteres.

   ```
   df %>% 
     mutate(V2 = str_replace(V2, 'roma', 'Roma'))
   ```
3. Ambas opciones, pero para todas las columnas de la tipo `character`

   ```
   df %>% 
     mutate_if(is.character, str_to_title) 

   df %>% 
     mutate_if(is.character, str_replace, 'roma', 'Roma')
   ```

En este último caso la sintaxis es un poco rara, pero nos evita usar la función anónima. Simplemente pasamos los argumentos que pasaríamos normalmente a `str_replace`, pero separados por comas y *sin paréntesis*.

Comment: Hola mpaladino, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, todavia no me introduje en el tydiverse, estoy recien arrancando con el uso de R, es emocionante, todo un mundo!!!